# Android webview app not loading https url of a wordpress site running on google app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ssl-certificate

I have all the android studio project file ready to build a webview app. But i am getting issue in opening a website build on google app engine with a SSL certificate attached to it. I followed the instruction provided by google to apply SSL on custom domain in google app engine. But my webview is not loading the https:// url. But when i remove the certificate then the normal http:// url is loading properly in my webview. One more thing i noticed that my desktop chrome browser is not showing any error in my SSL certification. But mobile crome browser is showing error CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. I tried certificates from startSSL and comodo both.
Please help me here folks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - GAE served https url working from the desktop but not working from Android tablet. Turned out that the (comodo) certificate I had installed was an incomplete one (missing intermediate authority) - confirmed using the [digicert](https://www.digicert.com/help/) site. After I re-generated the certificate correctly and installed it on GAE android was happy as well.